# Why is MySQL not using my index for JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, query-optimization

I have an incredibly complex query being produced by an ORM, but here's the relevant portions for the sake of this question:

```
SELECT
    ...
FROM
    `Broadcast` `t`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        `Site` `site`
        ON (`t`.`site_id` = `site`.`id`)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        `Customer` `customer`
        ON (`site`.`customer_id` = `customer`.`id`)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        `Domain` `domain`
        ON (`customer`.`domain_id` = `domain`.`id`)
    ...
```

My fields are defined as follows:

```
>SHOW FIELDS FROM Broadcast;
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+------+-----+------------------+----------------+
| Field                     | Type                                 | Null | Key | Default          | Extra          |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+------+-----+------------------+----------------+
| id                        | int(10) unsigned                     | NO   | PRI | NULL             | auto_increment |
| site_id                   | int(10) unsigned                     | NO   | MUL | NULL             |                |
...

>SHOW FIELDS FROM Site;
+---------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+------------------+----------------+
| Field                     | Type                | Null | Key | Default          | Extra          |
+---------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+------------------+----------------+
| id                        | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL             | auto_increment |
| customer_id               | int(11)             | NO   | MUL | 0                |                |
...

>SHOW FIELDS FROM Customer;
+---------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                        | int(11)          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| domain_id                 | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 1       |                |
...

>SHOW FIELDS FROM Domain;
+---------------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                           | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                              | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
...
```

Why some of our IDs are `int(11)` and others are `int(10) unsigned` is just a matter of historical context. What's important is that the `X_id` foreign key always shares a type with the relevant `id` column. We never attempt to link an `int(11)` with an `int(10) unsigned`. Also the `id` field is always the primary key for the table.

We also have indexes on all of the foreign keys:

```
>SHOW INDEXES FROM Broadcast;
+-----------+------------+---------------------------------------+--------------+---------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table     | Non_unique | Key_name                              | Seq_in_index | Column_name               | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-----------+------------+---------------------------------------+--------------+---------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Broadcast |          0 | PRIMARY                               |            1 | id                        | A         |      139708 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Broadcast |          1 | site_id                               |            1 | site_id                   | A         |        1060 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
...

>SHOW INDEXES FROM Site;
+-------+------------+----------------------------------+--------------+---------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name                         | Seq_in_index | Column_name               | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+----------------------------------+--------------+---------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Site  |          0 | PRIMARY                          |            1 | id                        | A         |        1876 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Site  |          1 | customer_id                      |            1 | customer_id               | A         |         250 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
...

>SHOW INDEXES FROM Customer;
+----------+------------+--------------------------------------+--------------+---------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table    | Non_unique | Key_name                             | Seq_in_index | Column_name               | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+----------+------------+--------------------------------------+--------------+---------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Customer |          0 | PRIMARY                              |            1 | id                        | A         |         292 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Customer |          1 | domain_id                            |            1 | domain_id                 | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
...

>SHOW INDEXES FROM Domain;
+--------+------------+-------------------------------------------+--------------+---------------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table  | Non_unique | Key_name                                  | Seq_in_index | Column_name                     | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------+------------+-------------------------------------------+--------------+---------------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Domain |          0 | PRIMARY                                   |            1 | id                              | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
...
```

Each of these indexes consists of a single field, so the field is the first sequence in the index.

When I run `EXPLAIN ...` on my query, the output I get looks as follows:

[image]

Site and Customer are joined with the `eq_ref` type, but Domain is joined with `ALL` type. Why is MySQL not using my index?

I can force MySQL to use my index by adding `USE INDEX FOR JOIN (domain_id)` after the Customer table name, but this causes a new issue:

[image]

The problem just moves up from the `Customer->Domain` relation to the `Site->Customer` relation. I can shift the problem up one further using `USE INDEX FOR JOIN (customer_id)` after the Site table name, and as you might expect this just causes the ***Site*** table to join with the `ALL` type instead of `eq_ref`

I can't for the life of me figure out why MySQL is refusing to use my indexes

Comment: is domain a table with very few rows?  the optimizer can decide using any index at all is not worth it for such a table

Comment: @ysth Yes, the domain table has either 1 or 2 rows depending on the environment where this system is running. So is it actually better not to use the index when there are few rows?

Comment: yes.  or at least it is not worth worrying about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @ysth in the comments:

MySQL will not use an index if the table you are joining has very few rows, as the overhead of reading an index from disk exceeds the benefits